# Determining if a sequence T is a sorting of a sequence S in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, sequence

I know that one can easily determine if a sequence is sorted in O(n) time. However, how can we insure that some sequence T is indeed the sorting of elements from sequence S in O(n) time?

That is, someone might have an algorithm that outputs some sequence T that is indeed in sorted order, but may not contain any elements from sequence S, so how can we check that T is indeed a sorted sequence of S in O(n) time?

Comment: If you really mean O() analysis, which is asymptotic in N, there is no O(n) solution to your question.

Comment: Years gone by, no answer able to (check and?) exploit T is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the length `L` of `S`.
2. Check the length of `T` as well. If they differ, you are done!
3. Let `Hs` be a hash map with something like `2L` buckets of all elements in `S`.
4. Let `Ht` be a hash map (again, with `2L` buckets) of all elements in `T`.
5. For each element in `T`, check that it exists in `Hs`.
6. For each element in `S`, check that it exists in `Ht`.

This will work if the elements are unique in each sequence. See wcdolphin's answer for the small changes needed to make it work with non-unique sequences.

I have NOT taken memory consumption into account. Creating two hashmap of double the size of each sequence may be expensive. This is the usual tradeoff between speed and memory.

Comment: Note that it should be a histogram `map:element->int` to make sure you handle duplicate elements with still getting `O(n)`. Other than that - nice solution.

Comment: -1: Hash maps are not magic and are not O(1).  A hash map has the same O() complexity of the collision-handling it employs.  If the hash map uses chaining, then building it is O(n^2).  If the hash map has a binary tree for each bin's overflow, it is O(log N).  This was the issue behind the recent tomcat DoS POST vulnerability.  In today's colleges, where Java 'knowledge' is dispensed as CS education, many students are misinformed into believing that hash maps can be used as you describe -- but that is wrong.  You have to consider what happens if there is a hash collision.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: I disagree. While hash tables are indeed `O(n^2)` *worst case* - they are `O(n)` *average case*.

Comment: @amit - You are wrong.  O() is an asymptotic measure.  Full hash maps are the same O() as the chaining strategy.

Comment: Heath, as long as your load factor is small enough to avoid collisions in the average case the time complexity for hash maps is constant. Of course I presume that the author creates a large enough hash map to store all values (since the length of the sequence is probably known already, or at least can be found out in linear time).

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: Asymptotic measure can be done for worst case, or average case. The Big-O notation is asymptotic notation of a *function* not an *algorithm*. An algorithm can be `O(n)` *average case* while still being `O(n^2)` *worst case*, since `f_worst_case != f_average_case`

Comment: @Emil - O() is an asymptotic measure.  Therefore your hash map is always full and the O() complexity of adding to it is the same as the overflow strategy.  Hashmaps only provide a 1/k speedup factor, where k is the number of bins, and a constant.  In O() notation, the 1/k factor disappears.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: Wrong again. `k` can be modified dynamically. This is called [rehashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Dynamic_resizing)

Comment: @amit - A full hash map average case is the same as the worst case.  Again, the hashmap only provides 1/k factor in front of the chaining strategy.  This is explained in many good books.  And rehashing itself is an O(N) chaining strategy, that's ano-brainer.  Give up your Java-background misinformation, it's just wrong.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: You forgot to read the last chapter of them maybe, `k` is not constant. The load balance is usually `~1/2-1/4`, meaning `2n < k < 4n`, which decays back to a constant. Rehashin is `O(n)` - but is done after `O(n)` OPS, which get back to `O(1)` amortized per OP

Comment: Heath, why are you assuming that the hashmap is full? Who in their right mind will create a hashmap with too few buckets? I would understand your complaints more if you pointed to the (very unlikely) scenario of hash collisions for almost every key or something like that, but with a good hashing function and a large enough hashmap, key collisions should be unlikely.

Comment: @Emil - the very definition of O() is asymptotic runtime as N approaches infinity.  See the book "Compared to what?"

Comment: Infinity is unimportant when you already know the size of the sequence (if it's not known it can be found out in linear time as well). Therefore I've removed the O from my answer so we can go on discussing the actual question asked.

Comment: @Emil - In that case you aren't talking about O() notation and shouldn't imagine you are.  The question asked about O() notation, in which case you do not know the value of N.

Comment: `lim(n->infinity) p(n) * 1/k <= lim(n->infinity) CONST * n / 1/2n = lim(n->infinity) CONST/2 = CONST/2` per op. you can also add `CONST2 * n / n` for rehashing after every `n` elements, and you are still in constant [on average] time per op

Comment: @amit, that's only true if we accept your mistaken assertion that we can replace k with 2n, which we cannot, because that's wrong.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: REHASHING. It's `O(n)` operations that happens once for `n` insertion, still `O(1)` realm

Comment: I've actually updated my answer again to explicitly deal with the hashmap size. Note that you should be able to figure out the size of the sequence in linear time, therefore assuring a large enough hashmap. The size of the hashmaps in this algorithm is determined by the size of the sequences and so we can indeed replace `k` by `2n`. This algorithm should be O(n) even when n goes to infinity.

Comment: @Emil - glad you get the point.  The next thing you have to do is estimate the probability of collision with each add even while using your "large" enough hash map.  Consider that the sequences may contain duplicated items, which obviously hash to the same bin.  The only hope for this type of solution is that you have N values in the range 0..M, then you can use an array of size M as your 'hash map' with an identity hash function.  Anyway, this kind of problem is what I'm getting at with my pet peeve -- hash maps do not have O(1) asymptotic add unless you can make assumptions about collisions.

Comment: @Emil - Meanwhile, making assumptions about collision probability is what got us all the recent HashMap DoS vulns.  Also, this topic is the reason Java provides TreeMap, which has O(log N) add instead of HashMap's O(N).

Comment: You can make assumptions about the collision ratio, if you discuss the best or average case. I agree that it's hard or impossible to solve this problem in O(n) for the worst-case scenario. I don't know why you are (once again :-)) talking about Java (we are focusing much more on functional programming in my CS department), but yes, this is one of the reasons binary trees are useful. Another reason is that binary trees often have smaller constant factors than hashmaps, therefore performing better in absolute terms for small datasets. We don't need to argue this since I think we both agree.

Comment: @Emil - The misunderstanding of Hashmap seems mostly to spring from those who are trained in Java.  Persons who learned algorithmic analysis prior to the advent of the "magical seeming" hash map know better.  (I.e., those who had to write their own hashed data structures and implement chaining or other overflow.) BTW, a Java TreeMap is a hash map in front of binary trees used for the overflowing.  A HashMap uses linear chaining.  And I assume the TreeMap trees are red-black, otherwise it's potentially still O(n) for worst case.

Comment: I think you should also consider the count of each element. For example, your solution will answer "Yes" for A = [1, 1, 2] and B = [1, 2, 2], but the answer should be "No".

Comment: Hadi, you are indeed correct. wcdolphin's answer provides the small changes needed to take count into account.

Comment: Heath, TreeMap is not a hash map. It states clearly in the manual that it's a Red-Black tree, though. TreeMaps can be traversed in sorted order in linear time. HashMaps does not, and cannot, make such guarantees. They do implement the Map interface which means you can use it in much the same way as a HashMap. Java's collections are different data structures, but behind a common interface, which makes it important that you actually know your data structures even as a Java programmer. The TreeMap manual page even mentions the CLR book!

Answer (score 1):

While Emil's answer is very good, you can do slightly better.

Fundamentally, in order for T to be a reordering of S it must contain all of the same elements. That is to say, for every element in T or S, they must occur the same number of times. Thus, we will:

Create a Hash table of all elements in S, mapping from the 'Element' to the number of occurrences.

Iterate through every element in T, decrementing the number of times the current element occurred.

If the number of occurrences is zero, remove it from the hash.

If the current element is not in the hash, T is not a reordering of S.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt what do you mean by 'magical hash maps'? This is a standard hash table that could be written by hand, all it requires is that the elements by hashable. Can you elaborate?

Comment: EDIT: (well, not permitted to edit a comment ,but anyways). Great point on the insertion complexity of a hash table! While I think you may have taken things a little bit far for this simple question, it will definitely encourage me to always think twice about asymptotic behavior of hash tables especially.

Comment: This is a good solution when non-unique elements can be present. I've updated my answer to refer to you :-) It's also a little better in memory consumption since it use only one hashmap. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Create a hash map of both sequences. Use the character as key, and the count of the character as value. If a character has not been added yet add it with a count of 1. If a character has already been added increase its count by 1.

Verify that for each character in the input sequence that the hash map of the sorted sequence contains the character as key and has the same count as value.

Comment: huh? That's a pretty random downvote..Hash map is used to for O(1) lookup time, it's not "magic" and this algorithm should work in O(n). Can you explain your downvote?

Comment: It's explained above.  O() is an asymptotic measure.  Hash maps devolve to their chaining strategy when evaluating O() complexity, because they are full when N is large.  If you allow the hash map to resize, it's also O(N) to resize.

Comment: Hashmap does not have O(1) look-up time.  Hashmap has O(1/k * p(N)) lookup time, where p(N) is the chaining (bin overflow) strategy and 1/k is a constant factor which disappears from O() notation.  Hashmaps have average constant run time for N < k, but that is not O() notation.  O() notation is for N -> infinity.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: And since usually `2n < k < 4n`, and `p(n)` is linear, it decays back to `O(1)` [again, on average case, and on amortized analysis]

Comment: @amit - N is *asymptotic*, do you know what that means?  Your assertion that 2n < k is false.  N > k under O(), otherwise it isn't O(), it's Theta().

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: `Theta(f(n))` if and only if `Omega(f(n))` and `O(f(n))`, so the fact that it is `Theta()` is not a contradiciton, and staying "it's not O() it's Theta()" is fundementally wrong, since every Theta() is also an O().

Comment: @amit - No, you're just wrong with regard to how O() notation is used.  For example, part of your assertion uses the word "usually" which is not common for mathematical proofs.  Your wrong beliefs are commonly held these days, even widespread.  But still wrong, and rude.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: I think you are not interpeting the `O()` correctly. it's not worst case bound. no-one says it is. There is no `O()` for algorithm, `O()` is used on functions. You can have 2 functions that denote the runtime for the same algorithms - f1 = worst_case, f2 = average_case, It is very possible that `O(f1(n))` will be different then `O(f2(n))`, FOR THE SAME ALGORITHM

Answer (score 0):

I believe it this is a O(n^2) problem because:

1. Assuming data structure you use to store elements is a linked list for minimal operations of removing an element
2. You will be doing a S.contains(element of T) for every element of T, and one to check they are the same size.
3. You cannot assume that s is ordered and therefore need to do a element by element comparison for every element.
4. worst case would be if S is reverse of T
5. This would mean that for element (0+x) of T you would do (n-x) comparisons if you remove each successful element.
6. this results in (n*(n+1))/2 operations which is O(n^2)

Might be some other cleverer algorithm out there though

Comment: It's not really O(N^2).  You can sort the second list in O(N log N), then compare the two in O(N).  So it's an O(N log N) problem.  You could also binary search (O log N) the sorted sequence for each element of the second sequence, but you have to be careful about counting the same number of duplicated items -- perhaps replace each matched item from the sort with a sentinel such -1, then this is destructive.  It's still O(N log N).